# exclude weekends from calendar jquery while using moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to display 3, 4, and 6 days into the future

```
<p class="day">
<script>
    var fourDaysForward = new moment().add(4, 'day');  
    document.write(fourDaysForward.format('dddd'+','+' MMMM'));
</script>
</p>

<p class="date">
<script>
    var fourDaysForward = new moment().add(4, 'day'); 
    document.write(fourDaysForward.format('DD'));
</script>
</p>
```

but I need to exclude weekends. So, I need a calendar that only does working days Mon-fri. Is that possible with moment.js or do i need to use something else?

**update**: OK to clarify more in case it was confusing, I would like some help with a calculation calendar that adds 4 days but excludes weekends so if it was Thursday and you added 4 it would be wed. not Mon.
how I'm using it: http://www.brokenarrowwear.com/responsivedesign/information/fast-turnaround.html

Comment: "holiday" and "working day" are very subjective terms that vary by country, perhaps town, and business. I've worked for 6 different companies. Each company had different holidays... And all those companies were within a 30mi radius. Make it world wide and who knows! Do the Chinese get off for Chinese New Year? I haven't a clue. I suspect you'll need to make an array of what you consider a holiday and exclude them yourself.

Comment: that's a good point. i'll just need help with taking off weekends then. thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: moment.js doesn't build calendars but has the mthods you need ...read the docs

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I need a calendar" do you mean you need a UI component?

Have you tried Adam Shaw's http://fullcalendar.io/ ?  It is very customizable, for ex:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    weekends: false // will hide Saturdays and Sundays
});
```

Fiddle with this config:  http://jsfiddle.net/jq7bgpdz/

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake i used the wrong wording. i'm displaying just the dates on the page. here's a link http://www.brokenarrowwear.com/responsivedesign/information/fast-turnaround.html

Answer (score 0):

If the locale assigns Monday as the first day of the week, moment().weekday(0) will be Monday. If Sunday is the first day of the week, moment().weekday(0) will be Sunday. With this in mind, the answer will be different. The answer below takes for granted that moment().weekday(0) will be Monday.

```
var offsets = [3, 4, 6];

for(var i = 0; i < offsets.length; i++) {
  var m = new moment().add(offsets[i], 'day');
  var weekday = m.weekday();

  // If weekday is either Saturday or Sunday, don't write.
  if(weekday !== 5 && weekday !== 6) {
    document.write(m.format('dddd MMMM DD'));
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried adding this in what i "think" was the right way but i'm still having sunday show up as an option, but thank you for trying!